# Do the 'OS X Beta Seed Program' updates wipe your existing OS install?

Tags: macos, mac, software-update

I've joined the OS X Beta Seed Program but am not sure about this detail. Does it upgrade 'in place' and all your countless system tweaks and customizations are kept in tact, or does it do a 'fresh' install and so you are forced to restore from backup all your apps, tweaked system files (such as `defaults write` variables), third-party prefpanes, and maybe even user documents, at your own initiative?

I didn't see anywhere that they address this.

Comment: You should always install such beta stuff on a separate empty partition somewhere so that whatever problems it might have does not destroy/disrupt your current working OS.

Comment: I have already seen people say that, but I am guessing this pretty far-down-the-line beta (not internal, not developer) is not too unstable - I'm actually pretty desperate to try and have little fixes/tweaks make my way sooner than normal public release, and my submitted question remains in either case - which is very useful to know regardless of this other matter you bring up. I may end up answering the question myself, as I (possibly) take the plunge anyway.

Comment: If you are worried about losing data, then the OS X Beta Seed Program is probably not something that you should be doing.  Generally, only developers and IT professionals should be using this software, and this software should probably be used on a spare machine or drive that cannot be damaged by a bad update.

Answer (score 2):

"Upgrade in place" doesn't touch your data, in theory. However, I would *always* backup your data before installing, especially beta releases. It's not supposed to change your data, but that's not guaranteed, particularly in a beta release

Comment: Could you clarify your answer a little further? Are the beta seed updates indeed of the 'upgrade in place' type? (You didn't actually specify that and that's the question I ask.) Thanks!

Comment: ok, well, as a guinea pig I can confirm also, that yes it DOES keep all your system settings. It appears to be fine - so far - from my observations.

Comment: I believe they are. Sorry, I think I misunderstood what exactly you asked.